# copy hdc contents to bitmap

Tags: c++, copy, bitmap, gdi

How could you copy the contents of an HDC to a bitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head I think you need to:

- Create a new DC compatible with the source DC. Call this the memory DC.
- Create a new bitmap of the correct size.
- Select the bitmap into the memory DC.
- BitBlt the source DC into the memory DC.
- The bitmap should now contain a copy of the source DC.

I'm at home so can't give you any code, so I hope this is enough to get you started.  There is a good GDI section on Code Project.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/

Answer (score 3):

There is a good piece of sample code [here](http://www.codexxi.com/MyBlocks.html#atBmpTest) that does just that (amongst other things).

I've used a similar technique before (many moons ago), but do not have the code to hand.