# Can you make a Winform draw on top of full screen DirectX layer?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, directx, winforms-interop

I have a native C++ application that is rendering 3D using DirectX. 
The app can switch between windowed and fullscreen using IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState().
However some of my UI is in a .Net Winform in a managed dll.

In windowed mode I just  call into the .Net dll and that opens the secondary Winform, so two windows, the main native MFC/DirectX and .Net Winform control.

But when the DirectX  is in full screen, can I get the Winform to be show above the Direct X layer?
Is it even possible?

Merely setting the Winform property 
this.TopMost = true; 
is not sufficient.   The winform is under the Direct X layer. 
I just want "my" WinForm over the full screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not possible. That's the whole point of the "full screen" mode—to allow the application to own the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could [copy your WinForm's DC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351236/copy-hdc-contents-to-bitmap) onto bitmap in memory and copy that onto a DirectX rendering [surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass messages back to the WinForm. It might be slow thow though, if you try to do very much.

Comment: ohh...tricky.  If you derive from System.Windows.Form you can implement  over rides for the Window Message Handler or Application.AddMessageFilter. Then  you can simulate desktop Focus and manually dispatch Window Messages to the Form. That way the dialog will get WM_PAINT and the mouse and keyboard events.   So it sounds at least possible, with sufficient effort.   ok cool.